# Could not determine access type for property "skills" in class "AppBundle\Entity\"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I make mapping manytomany in 2 entites but I have this error:

> Could not determine access type for property "skills" in class "AppBundle\Entity\".

code entity company:

```
/**
           * @var SkillInterface[]
           *
           * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Skill", inversedBy="companys", cascade={"all"})
           * @ORM\JoinTable(name="companys_has_skills",
           *   joinColumns={
           *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
           *   },
           *   inverseJoinColumns={
           *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="skill_id", referencedColumnName="id")
           *   }
           * )
           * @Assert\Count(min = 1)
           */
          private $skills;

          public function __construct()
          {
              $this->skills = new ArrayCollection();
          }


           /**
           * Add skills.
           *
           * @param SkillInterface $skills
           *
           * @return Company
           */
          public function addSkills(\AppBundle\Entity\Skill $skills)
          {
              $this->skills[] = $skills;

              return $this;
          }

          /**
           * Remove skills.
           *
           * @param SkillInterface $skills
           */
          public function removeSkills(\AppBundle\Entity\Skill $skills)
          {
              $this->skills->removeElement($skills);
          }

          /**
           * Get skills.
           *
           * @return Collection
           */
          public function getSkills()
          {
              return $this->skills;
          }
```

code entity skill:

```
/**
                * @var Collection
                *
                * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="skills")
                */
               private $companys;

                /**
                * Constructor.
                */
               public function __construct()
               {
                   $this->companys = new ArrayCollection();

               }

               /**
                * Add company.
                *
                * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Company $company
                *
                * @return Skill
                */
               public function addCompany(\AppBundle\Entity\Company $company)
               {
                   $this->companys[] = $company;

                   return $this;
               }

               /**
                * Remove company.
                *
                * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Company $company
                */
               public function removeCompany(\AppBundle\Entity\Company $company)
               {
                   $this->companys->removeElement($company);
               }

               /**
                * Get companys.
                *
                * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
                */
               public function getCompanys()
               {
                   return $this->companys;
               }
```

now i make functions of remove ,add and get variables in 2 entitys but I have also error and I initialize to arrayCollection

Answer (score 0):

Function names should be `addSkill` and `removeSkill` without `s`.

Comment: @dev_php is the error same? did you clear your cache?